# Apple phone 8+ and Apple Watch 7

Tags: iphone

I have the iPhone 8 Plus with iOS 16.7.2. I used to have an Apple Watch seven, it worked great paired with my 8+.  Then went with a different watch Verda 3 with no problems, and I missed my seven my husband bought me one today and my iPhone 8 Plus and my Apple Watch seven will not pair up. It says my Apple Watch 8+ is out of date.
Is there anything that can be done about this? If not, what Apple Watch can I use with my iPhone 8 Plus which I love? I don’t want to change it because I rarely use it..and I’m 81.

Comment: Make sure both your "iPhone 8 Plus" and "Apple Watch 7" are updated to the latest version, additionally ensure that both devices have Bluetooth enabled, and are close to each other during the pairing process.

Comment: That’s not the problem, found out the iPhone 8+ is IOS 16.7.2 and the Watch 7 has to have ios17.  
So no way it will work.  Need to find a Watch that will pair up to my iPhone.  Not wanting a new phone.  There has to be one that has fall detection and that I can contact my husband if I fall again.

Comment: You're correct! watchOS is the operating system that runs on the Apple Watch, and the latest released version is watchOS 10.1. This version requires iOS 17, but your iPhone 8+ does not support iOS 17. Additionally, it's not possible to downgrade your Apple Watch from watchOS 10 to watchOS 9.